# After I prompt the user to play again, the game goes back to it's previous random number instead of restarting

Tags: java

**Guessing Game trying to prompt the user to play again.**

I set it into a while loop, but for some reason it keeps using the same number of the previous game. Why is that? Do I have to add more detail to the while loop?

```
public class Guessing_zulueta {


public static int getOneInt() {
    //we will get one integer from the keyboard
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter an integer: ");
    return in.nextInt();
}


public static int random = getRand();

public static final int MAX = 100;


public static int getRand() {

    Random randGenerator = new Random();
    int x = randGenerator.nextInt(MAX);

    return x;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {//here is my problem
    while (true){
        guessingGame();
    System.out.println("Do you wish to play again? (1 for yes, -1 for no: ");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int val = scan2.nextInt();
    if (val == 1)
        guessingGame();
    if (val == -1)
        break;
    }

}

public static void guessingGame() {

        int input = getOneInt();

        if (input == random) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations");
        }

        if (input > random) {
            System.out.println("Too big.");
            guessingGame();
        }
        if (input < random) {
            System.out.println("Too small.");
            guessingGame();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the value of `random` only once when the class is loaded. To assign a new random number each time the game is played, you need to assign it before calling `guessingGame`.

I've also modified your loop slightly; previously you were calling `guessingGame()` if the user typed `1` and then calling it again at the beginning of the loop. Now it will only call it once if the user types `1` (or anything but `-1`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        random = getRand();
        guessingGame();

        System.out.println("Do you wish to play again? (1 for yes, -1 for no: ");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val = scan2.nextInt();
        if (val == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            // Any other value will continue to loop and play another game.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doing that it randomizes the number after every guess instead of after every game

Comment: Yeah sorry, I initially misread your code. I've updated my answer now.